# Why in function $f(x) = a^x$, a must be greater than zero?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Suppose a function $f(x) = a^x$
In this case $a$ must be greater than zero. If we take a number less than zero like $-0.5$ and suppose the value of $x$ as $2$ the function should have value of $0.25$ and thus this function should work and show a curve in graph. But I have tried in several graphing calculators and that have showed no results. So my question is why $a$ is greater than zero and can't be equal to one

Comment: Look what happens when $a=-2$ and $x=1/2$.

Comment: When a $a = -2$, $x = 1/2$ the values should be $4$ and $1/4$

Comment: a square root of negative number will involve complex number. If the domain and range are expanded to complex number, it indeed makes sense.

Comment: How, Md, do you get $(-2)^{1/2}=4$?

Comment: I am unable to understand. And there was no square root, there was square

Comment: Thank you $-2^{1/2}$ is undefined.

Comment: But there should be a curve(when $x$ is integer) in graph at right side of zero. But graphing calculator is not showing graph at all when $a < 0$

Comment: A "graph" restricted to "when $x$ is an integer" would just be a bunch of isolated dots – not much of a graph. When you try to fill in between the dots, you run into expressions that are undefined. There is nothing for the graphing calculator to show. By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you must put @Gerry into the comment.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Certainly there is one problem with this approach. The function is only defined for some values of $x$, for example when $x$ is an integer. In some nice cases, decimals can work as well, but it is not defined on the entire real line, which is why most calculators will likely complain. For example, there is no way, at least in the real line, to make sense of the expression $(-.5)^{\pi}$. Thus the graph will not be a curve, but a discrete collection of points. You can see this by plotting your function on desmos.com. You will have to create a table as well to see the points, but you'll see that this function is undefined for the majority of points, so likely most calculators will give up trying to plot it.

Comment: Thank you. Desmos is my favourite calculator